# Advancad calculus- recommendation

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, book-recommendation

I will take advancad calculus next semester, in this course, after completing the coverage of basic theorems about integration on R^n, the fundamental theorems of vector calculus are presented. Some of the topics are: Chage of Variables Theorem, Green, Gauss and Stokes's Theorems on parametric curves/surfaces (in 2 and 3 dimensions), tensors, differential forms, the general form of Stokes's Theorem.

Course content: change  of variables, parametric curves and surfaces, Green, Gauss and Stokes's Theorems (in 2 and 3 dimensions), Tensors, Differential forms
,exterior derivative, Revisiting Stokes's Theorem.

Can you reccommend books for beginners, online notes and can you give me advice that how should I study this course? Thanks...

Comment: There are literally dozens of posts like this already with many good recommendations if you search “advanced calculus [book-recommendation]” or “vector analysis [book-recommendation]”. Can you please make use of those instead of asking the $12n+1$th time? I’m certain everything you asked about is covered and covered well.

Answer (score 0):

We used Marsden and Tromba's *Vector Calculus* my second semester at Berkeley.  It covers most if not all of the mentioned topics. I would recommend it.

Make sure and attend all of the lectures.  Work lots of examples.  Go over the problems with fellow students, a TA, or anyone else in the know.
It helps to have people to talk to.